# Azure: Failed to add delegation to the existing subnet

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, vnet, express-router

I'm trying to include in an app service an existing VNET but I have this issue:

> Failed to add delegation to the existing subnet.:
> Delegations of subnet /subscriptions
> Cannot be changed from [] to [Microsoft.Web/serverfarms] because it is being used by the resource

Azure Limitation ? How many resources can be used by one VNET ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limit is that you have to use an **unused subnet** for your app service integration When you add **VNet (preview)** in the networking configuration of app service. Please check if you have any VM resources in that subnet. If it is, you could create an empty subnet for the VNet integration.  Read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration).

[image]

Comment: Why such requirement? When I integrate my webapp with my VNET I cannot put there Azure Container Instance with private address

Comment: Now in that link, there is a clear bullet point saying - "The integration subnet can be used by only one App Service plan."